# What does '&feature=related' mean in a YouTube URL?

Tags: url, youtube

I saw a couple another ones like 'feature=feedu', 'feature=relmfu' in a URL (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0&feature=relmfu). I can attach or remove these from the URL and nothing changes. Does anyone know what these parameters mean and what kind of information is being passed using these parameters?

Comment: Was removed in 2014 or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume they're being used for analytics.

Comment: Can you guess what they might stand for?

Comment: I have no idea what `relmfu` is, but `related` is when you click a video in the list of related videos to the side of another video.

Comment: Well maybe take it literally.
related means, that the link you clicked on was on youtube itself.

Answer (score 15):

`relmfu` is a related video from the user who uploaded the currently watched one:

**rel** ated **m** ovie **f** rom **u** ser

Answer (score 2):

After a video completes, a grid of videos that YouTube suggests you watch that it believes are related to this video, appear and are clickable. When you click one of those, the URL is replaced with that video's URL with the &feature=related tacked on the end so that it knows statistically as confirmation that you clicked it (as a presumption). It will update other videos with higher click-thru counts as "related" to that video.  When people post a video with that &feature=related part on the end, they're just copying the address as a whole not knowing that section needs to be removed..

Answer (score 1):

Related Electronic Labeled Movie From User

Comment: Where can I find this info? Are you God?

Answer (score 0):

From my testing on getting the link it means that they were selected from a related video category. Likely used to check relevancy to other videos (or so I would assume). **EDIT** from reading comments on previous answer, I'd like to specify that I got this when I did click other videos on the side.